# Magento Checkout page as home page

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, addtocart

I have only one product and I have to sell directly and not via product page or home page. When visiting the site URL it should directly add a product into the cart and redirect to checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an observer to, for example, `controller_action_predispatch` and check for products in the cart. However make sure the checkout URL's ship this.

The observer would look something like

```
public function checkProductAdded($o) 
{ 
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    if (count($cart->getAllItems())) {
        return $this;
    }

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load([id of product]);
    $params = array('qty' => 1);

    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);

    $cart->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("checkout/cart"));
}
```

Didn't test it but with a little tweaking it should work